# Re-order Map based on ordering of List

Tags: java, list, sorting, hashmap

Lets say I have two data structures, an ordered List of Strings and a HashMap. The List looks like:

```
types = ["string", "integer", "boolean", "integer"];
```

And the HashMap, with an object key and a String value, that looks like:

```
map = {2=integer, true=boolean, 7=integer, "dog"=string};
```

Whats the easiest/most efficient way to reorganize the "order" of the Map so that the Map's values align with the ordering of the list, i.e., the Map would now look like this when printed:

```
map = {"dog"=string, 2=integer, true=boolean, 7=integer};
```

Comment: That looks likely to be a pain, and will probably require at least one extra map...

Comment: Will the `types` list always have the same size as the expected sorted map?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Yep; each is required to be the same size.

Comment: Good! @mettleap has [the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52978668/1876620), then.

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` does not offer an order guarantee. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

So if you wanted an ordered `Map` you'd normally want to start with an implementation of `SortedMap` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)).

Unfortunately, `SortedMap` sorts by key, and you want to sort by value, so you're either going to have to look at third-party collection libraries or consider something like `LinkedHashMap` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)), which has a predictable iteration order, even if it doesn't maintain a sort.

What strategy would you be using to decide which integer to use when there's two as your example shows?

Comment: Get all key-value pairs from original hashmap, sort them by value and then put them in a LinkedhashMap or SortedMap

Comment: Notice in the example there are two `integer` values in the ordering, one in the middle, one at the end -- which integer should be which?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, I wrote an answer. You could build a reversed map and then proceed

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman, In case of two integers the order does not matter.

Comment: I threw the two integers in there just for the sake of having multiple values of the same type - I could have easily just added a second string or boolean value instead. But for what I was asking, order of the same type didn't particularly matter - 7 could just have easily came before 2 in the reordering - as long as each was put into a integer "slot".

Answer (score 1):

Build a reverse hashmap like so,

```
types = ["string", "integer", "boolean", "integer"];

map = {2=integer, true=boolean, 7=integer, "dog"=string};

reversedmap = {integer=[2,7], boolean=true, string=dog};
```

then iterate through the list and the get the corresponding keys from the reversedmap.

for example, first you get "string" from types -> so you know the corresponding key should be "dog". Insert this key-value pair in some other map (of type `LinkedHashMap`). Keep on doing this till you reach the end of types list.

EDIT: Thank you @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner for pointing this out.

If you get two values from the reversedmap (for eg, in case of "integer" element), you can choose one of them (doesn't matter which) to be inserted in the LinkedHashMap while also subsequently removing it from the reversedmap. And then you procced to the next element in the types list

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, thank you :). But I did not understand your suggestion for the final part. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused, order of elements within each list doesn't matter. But you need to remove an element from the list once you put it in the map, so the next time there's an element of the same type to put in the map, you just pick another one from the list.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner,ohk. Actually, but even that isn't required I think. Once you get multiple values from reversedmap, proceed only after you have inserted all the possible key-value pairs into the LinkedHashMap

Comment: No, you have to respect encounter order of the `types` list. For the example in the question, you first find `(string, [dog])` in the `types` list, then go to the reversed map and put `(dog, string)` in the `LinkedHashMap`, and also remove `dog` from the list of the value of the reverse map. The next element in the `types` list is `integer`, you find `(integer, [2, 7])` in the reverse map. Here you should pick either `2` or `7` and *remove* it. Suppose you've picked and removed `2`, so put `(2, integer)` in the `LinkedHashMap`. Then go on with `boolean` and then with `integer` again...

Comment: ...(continued) When you find `integer` in the `types` list again, you'll only have `(integer, [7])` in the reverse map. Pick and remove `7` from the list of the value of the reverse map and put `(7, integer)` in the `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, Ohk ... got it now :) ... thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182461/discussion-between-federico-peralta-schaffner-and-mettleap).